# java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error

Tags: react-native

Following error occurred while I was trying to run my android app on device(react-native).

I have latest react dependencies:
"react": "~16.0.0-alpha.6"
"react-native": "~0.44.2"

Please find stacktrace of error occurred below:

Stacktrace:

```
Got JS Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (index.android.bundle:1)

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (index.android.bundle:1)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:24)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:156)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:481)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$700(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:51)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:497)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:33)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208)
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                           Caused by: com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (index.android.bundle:1)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                           Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (index.android.bundle:1)
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                              at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:208) 
                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

---

index.android.bundle :

```
{"from":"/Users/Workspace/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/React.js","to":"react/lib/React","message":"Unable to resolve module `react/lib/React` from `/Users/Workspace/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/React.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:\n  /Users/Workspace/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react/lib\n,   /Users/Workspace/react-native-app/node_modules/react/lib\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "(cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug)",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "build-ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --
entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle --platform 
\"ios\" --assets-dest ./  --dev false --reset-cache",
"build-android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js 
bundle --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle 
--platform \"android\" --assets-dest ./  --dev false --reset-cache",
"ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios",
"android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-
android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "clevertap-react-native": "~0.1.2",
    "immutable": "~3.8.1",
    "react": "~16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "~0.44.2",
    "react-native-code-push": "^2.0.3-beta",
    "react-native-collapsible": "~0.7.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "~0.4.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "~0.8.1",
    "react-native-htmlview": "~0.5.0",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "~1.1.1",
    "react-native-icon-checkbox": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "~0.2.1",
    "react-native-message-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "~0.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation-redux-helpers": "~0.4.1",
    "react-native-popup-dialog": "~0.3.15",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "~0.13.0",
    "react-native-simple-gesture": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-snackbar": "~0.2.0",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "~0.1.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-viewpager": "~0.2.12",
    "react-redux": "~4.4.5",
    "redux": "~3.5.2",
    "redux-immutable": "~3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "~0.9.5",
    "reselect": "~2.4.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "babel-eslint": "~6.0.2",
   "babel-polyfill": "~6.7.4",
   "eslint": "~2.8.0",
   "eslint-loader": "~1.3.0",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "~4.3.0",
   "remote-redux-devtools": "~0.1.6"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method

From your react native folder run:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

THEN

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Notes:

For mac you may need to change gradlew to ./gradlew

Could you post you package.json dependency

Comment: Could you post you package.json dependency